# a play-timeline like plugin for jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, timeline, playback

i was wondering whether there was a 'play timeline' plugin for jquery -- the play works like the play feature on any typical video player, but instead of playing a video, i just it to move through a timeline. i understand what i'm asking for is relatively vague, so any suggestions are welcomed.

edit: http://meyerweb.com/eric/browsers/timeline-structured.html

if there was a player on something like that that moved through this, this is something that i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using the jquery's slider and animation functionality to achieve what i wanted.